# Jasper PDF not downloading in internet explorer...working on Mozilla/Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, jasper-reports

In my rest webservice code I'm trying to send a Jasper PDF response as StreamingOutput object inorder to generate a PDF and be available for download on the browser.

/*Method to get the Streaming Output object*/

```
public static StreamingOutput getStream(final ByteArrayOutputStream pdfBytes) {
        StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                for (byte b: pdfBytes.toByteArray())
                 {
                    writer.write(b);
                 }
                writer.flush();
            }
        };
        return stream;
    }
```

/*Response build.*/

```
NewCookie fileDownloadCookie = new NewCookie(DealingConstants.FILE_DOWNLOAD_COOKIE, TRUE_CONSTANT, SLASH_CONSTANT, null, null, -1, false);
        Response response=  Response.ok(streamingOut).type(contentType)
        .header(DealingConstants.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, DealingConstants.ATTACHMENT_FILENAME+fileName)
        .cookie(fileDownloadCookie).build();
```

---

In Mozilla/Chrome the response is successful and a pop up opens up for downloading the pdf but in case of IE the response is always pending.
Can anyone help me on this???